# synonym with 'aside'

Tags: synonyms

I remember seeing a word that has the same meaning as [aside](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/aside_2) - *something that a character in a play says to the audience*, *but which the other characters on stage are not intended to hear* - perhaps longer than this one. But I don’t find it on synonym dictionaries. Is it my illusion that I saw it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [stage whisper](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stage+whisper).

`n.
1. The conventional whisper of an actor, intended to be heard by the audience but supposedly inaudible to others on stage.`

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is not exactly the same but have you looked at "soliloquy"?

Comment: It would be helpful to include the definition and explain why you think it applies so that your answer can stand on its own without needing the reader to do more research.